# Encoding an image from a file into base 64 bytes into a memory stream (Amazon AWS)

Tags: vb.net, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get a short proof of concept up using Amazon AWS Textract ([Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=Textract/TDocument.html&tocid=Amazon_Textract_Model_Document)).

According to the documentation I should be able to call and pass in a Amazon.Textract.Model.Document

The document can be in Bytes or a S3Object, the documentation reads:

> Properties: Bytes - System.IO.MemoryStream
>
> Gets and sets the property Bytes.
>
> A blob of base-64 encoded documents bytes. The maximum size of a document that's provided in a blob of bytes is 5 MB. The document bytes must be in PNG or JPG format.
>
> If you are using an AWS SDK to call Amazon Textract, you might not need to base64-encode image bytes passed using the Bytes field.

So my very simple example is throwing a 400 Bad Request exception from AWS. I'm not sure if i have encoding the image correctly, or if i have some other issue.

```
    Dim bData As Byte()
    Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(FileName))
    bData = br.ReadBytes(br.BaseStream.Length)
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bData, 0, bData.Length)
    ms.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length)
    Dim Client = New AmazonTextractClient()
    Dim Obj = New Model.AnalyzeDocumentRequest
    Dim Doc = New Model.Document
    Doc.Bytes = ms
    Obj.Document = Doc
    Dim OCR = Client.AnalyzeDocument(Obj)
    Console.WriteLine(OCR.HttpStatusCode)
    Console.WriteLine(OCR.ResponseMetadata)
```

Just a simple little example, new to AWS so i'm not sure if there is an issue with my actual request, or further up in my AWS configuration.